# Booting Ubuntu On Live USB Gives Black Screen after GRUB

Tags: macbook-pro

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.01 onto a 8GB USB stick using Universal USB installer just like it said on the website for windows. Once that had finished installing it onto the USB stick I rebooted my laptop and then booted onto the USB stick. It booted into a screen that gave me the options to install Ubuntu, try Ubuntu without installing and check the disk drive. I selected to try Ubuntu and it gave me a black screen. After a while my keyboard lit up and I waited for about 5 mins and I force shutdown my laptop and I am now writing this.

My laptop is a Early 2011 Refurbished 15" Macbook Pro. It has 8GB of ram, Intel i7 quad core, 1 integrated intel 4000 HD GPU and it also has a AMD Radeon HD 6490M.

I have done some research into this subject and I have not find much that relates to my situation.

I would like to say thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know most Macbooks running on an Intel processor and maybe you downloaded the wrong version for the wrong processor. Maybe you downloaded the version for AMD Processors.

Comment: Maybe. I did download it blindly on my windows partition. Ill look around and see if I can find the right one.